# How to make a custom Dialog which will display once a day

Tags: java, android

I am doing an application in which a I want to implement a custom dialogn in the main activity.
The thing is a want this dialog to be displayed once a day.
How can I accomplished that ?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail, like do you want to display the alert at a particular time or so..

Answer (score 2):

For custom dialog 
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

And to open application once in a day you can use alarm manager which triggers on some specific time. If you want dialog box to open when user starts your app then you need to write some logic using shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert.xml in one TextView and Button in id 
TextView  id =  alert_TV
Button id = alert_bnt

    {
        myDialog = new Dialog(this);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert);
        myDialog.setTitle("name give ");
        myDialog.setCancelable(true);
                TextView alertTitle = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_TV);
            alertTitle.setText("Date set"); 
            Button set = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_bnt);
                                   .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        myDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                    myDialog.show();
    }
```